# the app.config file is not getting include in sharepoint user controls files

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, configuration, visual-studio-2012, user-controls

here am creating one sharepoint user control in which I need to use some data which I am putting in app.config file and trying to use that in in ascx.cs file but that is not accessible any how,does any one have any idea of this?

Comment: You want to get data from the app.config to use in the codebehind c# file?

Comment: yes,but in sharepoint solution where am creating user control